# "Скучати за ..." чи "сумувати за ..."?

Tags: дієслова, вживання-слів

Чи вживається вираз "я скучаю за тобою" в сучасній розмовній українській, чи його частіше замінюють на "я сумую за тобою"?

Академічний тлумачний словник вказує, що кілька десятиліть тому обидва вирази вживались:

**[СУМУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/sumuvaty)**

> //  за ким — чим, без кого — чого, розм. по кому — чому. Горювати, тужити за ким-, чим-небудь. *Мала [Ліда] для всіх любов.. За тою з моїх сестер буду я сумувати, мамо, доки мого життя... (Ольга Кобилянська, II, 1956, 310); — За Україною все сумуєте? — Нема коли особливо сумувати: на оборону працюємо... (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 180); — Не сумуй же тут без мене. я швидко повернуся (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 360)*;

**[СКУЧАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/skuchaty)**

> 2. за ким—чим, без кого — чого і без додатка. Почувати тугу через відсутність кого-, чого-небудь, сумувати без когось, чогось. ***Скучаю** я не за Києвом, а за своєю родиною, за вами і за доброю, нормальною роботою (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 230); Біля воріт виладналися по-святочному зодягнуті старі козаки, які скучали за військом, як мати за дітьми (Петро Панч, Гомон. Україна, 1954, 446); — Чого ти, Мелашко, журишся, аж з лиця спала? — питав у неї чоловік. — Скучила за матір'ю (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 325); Кілька тижнів Франка не бачилася з подругою і дуже за нею скучила (Степан Чорнобривець, Потік.., 1956, 84); Розказала [Маруся] й те, як скучала і журилась без нього (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 60); Данило й не згадує про сестру, наче зроду її й не було, а стара дуже скучав (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 98); — Ой, а я скучаю вже! Мамонька мені приснилась, ще й якесь село... чуже (Павло Тичина, II, 1957, 324); Говорила [Лукія], що життя їхнє ще наладиться.., скучить [чоловік] — сам ще й просити прийде (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 147)*;

Навздогін: як правильно утворити імператив: "не скуч/скучай за мною"?

Comment: Зауважте, що перфектна форма **ску́чив/ску́чила** є також вживаною. Навіть наведена вами цитата із СУМ містить *«Скучила за матір'ю»*. І якщо імперфект *«скуча́ти»* може викликати сумніви, то перфект вигляда цілком незаперечним.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Дієслово "скучати" фіксує не тільки СУМ, але й дорепресивні словники.

**Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)** 
Скучать – скуча́ти, -ча́ю, -ча́єш, нудьгува́ти, -гу́ю, -гу́єш (за ким).
Соскучиваться, соскучиться – скуча́ти, заскуча́ти, -ча́ю, -ча́єш, ску́чити, -чу, -чиш (за ким, за чим).

**Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)**
Скуча́ти, -ча́ю, ску́чити, -чу (за ким, чим) – скучать, соскучиться по ком, чем.

**Словарь української мови 1909р. (Б. Грінченко)** 
Скуча́ти, -ча́ю, -єш, сов. в. ску́чити, -чу, -чиш, гл. Скучать, соскучиться. Скучає, як собака за києм. Ном. № 5021. Ти б поїхав та й не барився, щоб я не скучила. Мет. 56.

**Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)** 
Соску́чиваться, соску́читься = нудитись, зану́джувати ся (С. Аф.), скуча́ти, зану́дитись (С. Л.), зну́дити ся, ску́чити. — Скучила до дому. — Скучила за вами. Кр.

Можливо деякі пуристи намагаються його уникати або навішувати на нього ярлик "росіянізм", але це укаїнське слово та не треба його цуратися.

Дзвінка Матіяш:

> "Але ти просив мене писати тобі, писати ... І я нічого більше не
>   роблю, тільки *скучаю за тобою*. Тихо без слів *скучаю за тобою*."

Гордасевич Галина:

> Я скучаю за тобою.
>    Чи мовчу, чи розмовляю,
>    Чи на людях веселюся,
>    Чи сумую в самоті —
>
> *Я скучаю за тобою!*
>    Хочу голос твій почути.
>    Слухаю співочих птахів,
>    Слухаю розмови мудрі,
>    Слухаю пісні Дассена ...

Answer (score 9):

[Всесвітній словник української мови](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) ставить ці слова в один синонімічний рядок без вказання заст. чи діал.:

> **СУМУВА́ТИ** (пройматися почуттям суму, журби), ЖУРИ́ТИСЯ, ПЕЧА́ЛИТИСЯ, СМУТИ́ТИСЯ, ТУЖИ́ТИ підсил., ПОБИВА́ТИСЯ підсил.,
>   ВБИВА́ТИСЯ [УБИВА́ТИСЯ] підсил., СМУТКУВА́ТИ розм., КРУШИ́ТИСЯ заст.,
>   фольк., БАНУВА́ТИ діал., ПЕЧА́ЛУВАТИ діал., ПЕЧА́ЛУВАТИСЯ діал.;
>   НУДЬГУВА́ТИ, **СКУЧА́ТИ** (за ким-чим, без кого-чого і без додатка -
>   сумувати без когось, чогось).

`Скучати за` можна зустріти у багатьох творах та ЗМІ, наприклад, у Євгена Гуцало в творі `Дорога з дитинства`:

> Погостювавши тиждень-другий, починала **скучати за домівкою**, за селом,
>   за сусідами. Вже не розказувала нічого про нечистий дух та водяників,
>   а тільки зітхала й раз у раз дивилась у вікно. Мати клала в її кошик
>   буханець хліба, крупи, пшона, шматок сала, а баба від усього
>   відмовлялась, викладаючи. Тепер уже гнівалась мати.

Проте, `скучати по домівці` є неправильною формою вжитку. У довіднику з українського слововживання М. Волощак [наводиться](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/pryimennyky) таке пояснення:

> Скучати по домівці ― Сумувати (тужити) за домівкою